# light up the mass storage's led

Tags: python, io, usb, pyusb

I have usb mass stroage with led

I am trying to light on and off the led

using usb packet sniffing tool USBlyzer,

I can get the raw data

55 53 42 43 58 66 93 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

whose Request info is Bulk or Interrupt Transfer and I/O is out

and in the USB properties section

I can get the info such as

Endpoint Descriptor 81 1 In, bulk, 512 bytes

```
bDescriptorType 05h Endpoint

bEndpointAddress 81h 1 In
```

Endpoint Descriptor 02 2 In, bulk, 512 bytes

```
bDescriptorType 05h Endpoint

bEndpointAddress 02h 2 Out
```

I made a python code with python 2.7, libusb-win32-bin-1.2.4.0, pyusb-1.0.0-a1

the full source is here

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

# find our device
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1516, idProduct=0x8628)

# was it found?
if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device not found')

dev.set_configuration()
# get an endpoint instance
cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
interface_number = cfg[0].bInterfaceNumber
alternate_setting = usb.control.get_interface(interface_number)
intf = usb.util.find_descriptor(cfg, bInterfaceNumber = \
                                ineterface_number, bAlternateSetting = alternate_setting)
ep = usb.util.find_descriptor(intf,custom_match = \
                                  lambda e: \
                                      usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == \
                                      usb.util.ENDPOINT_OUT)
# set the active configuration. With no arguments, the first
# configuration will be the active one


assert ep is not None

ep.write(0x2,0x55)
ep.write(0x2,0x53)
ep.write(0x2,0x42)
ep.write(0x2,0x43)
ep.write(0x2,0x58)
ep.write(0x2,0x66)
ep.write(0x2,0x93)
ep.write(0x2,0x88)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x06)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
ep.write(0x2,0x00)
```

but when I try to execute it,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\kty1104\Desktop\usb2.py", line 14, in <module>
    interface_number = cfg[0].bInterfaceNumber
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 447, in __getitem__
    return Interface(self.device, index[0], index[1], self.index)
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

arise

what's wrong with my code?

any if anything wrong concept is there, please let me know

thanks!

Comment: cfg is an `int`. `dev.get_active_configuration()` is returning an integer

Comment: But the exception isn't being thrown at `cfg[0]`, it's being thrown at `index[0]`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about pyusb, but my interpretation of the error message is that, contra others' opinions, `cfg` is not an integer, but that it requires a non-integral index. I say this because the exception is thrown in a `__getitem__` function, which could only be `cfg`'s `__getitem__`, because that's the only place a `__getitem__` call would be made in the line

```
interface_number = cfg[0].bInterfaceNumber
```

Now if `cfg` were an int, it wouldn't have a `__getitem__`. The problem is that `cfg`'s `__getitem__` seems to expect to be able to subscript the `index` that it receives, as illustrated by the middle two arguments, `index[0], index[1]`. Since you passed `cfg` an integer, that's impossible.

---

From the [tutorial](http://pyusb.sourceforge.net/docs/1.0/tutorial.html):

> You can also use the subscript
>   operator to access the descriptors
>   randomly, like that:

```
>>> # access the second configuration
>>> cfg = dev[1]
>>> # access the first interface
>>> intf = cfg[(0,0)]
>>> # third endpoint
>>> ep = intf[2]
```

> As you can see, the index is zero based. But wait! There
>   is something weird in the way I access
>   an interface... Yes, you are right,
>   the subscript operator in the
>   Configuration accepts a sequence of
>   two items, with the first one being
>   the index of the Interface and the
>   second one, the alternate setting. So,
>   to access the first interface, but its
>   second alternate setting, we write
>   cfg[(0,1)].

Comment: The official documentation recommends iterating over the objects, like `for intf in cfg:`. http://pyusb.sourceforge.net/docs/1.0/tutorial.html

Comment: @ulidtko, yes, I saw that, but I was hoping for a more detailed class reference to confirm my guess. Is the tutorial the only documentation available?

Comment: I'm afraid it is. I can't find any class reference too. Nevertheless, as you pointed out, the tutorial contains explanations about the indexing: the interface index must be a pair of ints.